# How to encode ffmepg for jwplayer script which script read pass php file?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, media-player, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have encoded my video use this command.

```
$encode_comand="ffmpeg -i  $input_path -ac 1 -ab 128k -y -vcodec libx264 -vpre ultrafast -g 30 -r 30 -crf 22 $target_path &";

exec($encode_comand);
```

And it work for script below

```
    echo '<!-- START OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING TO COPY-PASTE -->
                <div id="mediaplayer'."11111".'" style="margin:0px auto; text-align:center; width:auto; display:blog;" class="vdoplayer">JW Player goes here</div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="OOD7GkWbyNXOL6MbstF2Sa/YrQPgtNUPqxm5NA==";</script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                                jwplayer("mediaplayer'."11111".'").setup({
                                flashplayer: "jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                                file: "$video_file",                            
                                width: "'.$width.'",
                                height: "'.$height.'",
                                stretching: "uniform",
                                type: "mp4",
                                skin: "jwplayer/jwplayer-skins-free/six.xml",

                        });
                </script>
                <!-- END OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING -->'
//$video_file="http://myhost.com/project/files/1/video/file3.mp4";
```

But After I chang script

```
echo '<!-- START OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING TO COPY-PASTE -->
            <div id="mediaplayer'."11111".'" style="margin:0px auto; text-align:center; width:auto; display:blog;" class="vdoplayer">JW Player goes here</div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="OOD7GkWbyNXOL6MbstF2Sa/YrQPgtNUPqxm5NA==";</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                            jwplayer("mediaplayer'."11111".'").setup({
                            flashplayer: "jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                            file: "readfile.php",                            
                            width: "'.$width.'",
                            height: "'.$height.'",
                            stretching: "uniform",
                            type: "mp4",
                            skin: "jwplayer/jwplayer-skins-free/six.xml",
                            abouttext: "project",
                            aboutlink: "project",
                    });
            </script>
            <!-- END OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING -->'
```

It not work for my video encode,But i try video that not encode it work.

**Video** 
Dimension: 853 x 840 
codec : H.264 
Framerate : 30 frames per second 
Bitrate 408 kbps 
**Audio** 
codec : MPEG-4 AAC 
channels: Stero 
Sample rate: 44100 Hz ์
Bitrate : N/A

**Readfile.php** that have function read file

```
<?php 
    $filename= 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4'; //can read
    $video_file = "http://myhost.com/project/files/1/video/file3.mp4"; 
    //cannot read Same file as script below

    if (file_exists($video_file)) { ob_clean(); flush(); };
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.mp4');
    readfile($video_file);
    ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Under:

```
file: "$video_file",
```

Add:

```
type: "mp4",
```

Comment: yes, i found some file can play some file not.So i see file property and file which not play sample rate on audio is N/A

Comment: Video property -----
Dimension: 853 x 840
codec : H.264
Framerate : 30 frames per second
Bitrate 408 kbps

Audio Property --- 
codec : MPEG-4 AAC
channels: Stero
Sample rate: 44100 Hz
์Bitrate : N/A

Comment: file: "http://myhost.com/project/files/1/video/file3.mp4" === can play. 
file: "checkfile.php" === can not play

Comment: This is because you need to set the player's "type" variable to "mp4", per my answer above. If you can provide a link, we can troubleshoot further.